# Linear system of ODE from quadratic functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $N$ independent quadratic functions such as
$$x_i(t)=a_it^2 + b_it +c_i$$
is there a linear system of ODEs
$$\dot{x}_i=f(x_i)$$
such that the ODEs depend on $x_i$ and not (directly) on $t$? Of course, one can just take the derivative of $x_i$: $\dot{x}_i=2a_it + b_i$, but this does not yield a system of ODEs. Also, is there a name for this process? I have been able to find the system of ODEs using a data-driven approach, but the fact that its numerical integration yields to machine-precision error when compared to $x_i$ makes me think there is an analytical way to find such ODEs system. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the $x_i$ scalars?  Then $N \le 3$.  And if $N = 3$ you have
$$ \pmatrix{x_1\cr x_2\cr x_3\cr} = A \pmatrix{1\cr t \cr t^2\cr}$$
for some invertible $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$.  Then
$$\pmatrix{\dot{x_1}\cr \dot{x_2}\cr \dot{x_3}} = A \pmatrix{0 \cr 1 \cr 2 t\cr} = A \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0\cr 1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 2 & 0\cr} \pmatrix{1 \cr t \cr t^2}
 = A \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0\cr 1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 2 & 0\cr} A^{-1} \pmatrix{x_1 \cr x_2\cr x_3\cr} $$

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) $x_i$ are scalars, but why would this mean that $N\leq3$? In fact, I have more than 3 quadratic equations.

Comment: Then they're not linearly independent.

Comment: How so? $A$ can be a $N\times3$ rectangular matrix for which I can compute a pseudo-inverse. And in this case, it seems that I am correctly recovering the ODE system coefficient using your approach.